# Problema con subscribe

Tags: angular, web

Estoy implementando un formulario en Angular 10 para crear salas de chat y tengo un problema derivado de subscribe.
En un principio creí que el método finalize no llegaba a llamarse, pero, tras hacer pruebas vi que el problema era de subscribe, concretamente del siguiente código:

```js
if (this.form.valid) {
      const formValue = { ...this.form.value };
      const body: chat = formValue as chat;
      this.loading = true;
      this.ChatService.crearchat(body)
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          this.loading = false;
        })
      )
      .subscribe((x) => {
        this.messageService.add({
          severity: 'info',
          life: environment.modalTime,
          summary: 'Chat creado con éxito',
          detail: '' + x,
        });
        this.router.navigate(['/chat/home']);
      });
    } else {
     this.messageService.add({
        severity: 'error',
       life: environment.modalTime,
      summary: 'Formulario incorrecto',
      detail:
         'Asegúrese de rellenar todos los campos respetando el formato.',
      });
    }
```

Adjunto también el resto de código que he utilizado para implementar el formulario.

**crearchatcomponent.html**

```
<div class="locomotion_container">
  <div class="locomotion_center_bloque font">
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" method="post">
      <div>
       <label for="nombre"> Nombre del chat</label>
        <input  id="chatname" type="text" name="nombre"  formControlName="nombre" /> <br /> -->
      <label for="componentes"> Número máximo de personas del chat</label>
      <input  id="chatcomponentes" type="int" name="componentes" formControlName="componentes"  /> <br />
      <br />
</div>
      <button id="botonCrear" class="button" type="submit">Crear chat</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Models**

**chat.ts**

```js
export interface chat{
    id: number;
    nombre: string;
    componentes: number;
}
```

**chatestado.ts**

```
export interface chatestado{
    chatActivo: boolean;
}
```

**chatrespuesta.ts**

```
export interface chatResponse{
    id: number;
}
```

**chat.service.ts**

```
import { ChatEstado } from './../models/chat/chatestado';
import { HttpClient, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { chat } from '../models/chat/chat';
import { ChatRespuesta } from '../models/chat/chatrespuesta';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
 
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class ChatService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  private static readonly ENDPOINT: string = 'chat';
  id = '';
  crerchat(body: chat): Observable<Chatrespuesta> {
    return this.httpClient.post<ChatRespuesta>(
      `${environment.url}${ChatService.ENDPOINT}`,
      body
    );
  }

  getChatEstado(id: number): Observable<ChatEstado> {
  return this.httpClient.get<ChatEstado>(
      `${environment.url}${ChatService.ENDPOINT}/get-status/${chatCode}`
    );
  }
}
```

**crearchat.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChatService } from 'src/app/services/chat.service';
import { chatRespuesta } from 'src/app/models/chat/chatrespuesta';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/services/data.service';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { delay, finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {chat} from 'src/app/models/chat/chat';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-crearchat',
  templateUrl: './crearchat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./crearchat.component.scss'],
})

export class CreatechatComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  loading: boolean;
  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private ChatService: ChatService,
    private router: Router,
    private messageService: MessageService,
    public dataService: DataService

  ) {

    this.loading = false;

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({

 

     componentes:new FormControl(''),

 

      nombre:new FormControl(''),

      id: new FormControl(1),//El id tiene que generarse automáticamente,

      //pero en principio pongo uno de prueba

 

    });

 

}

 

ngOnInit(): void {}

  onSubmit(): void {

 

    if (this.form.valid) {

 

      const formValue = { ...this.form.value };

 

      const body: chat = formValue as chat;

 

      this.loading = true;

 

      this.ChatService.crearchat(body)

      .pipe(

 

        finalize(() => {

          this.loading = false;

        })

      )

      .subscribe((x) => {

 

        this.messageService.add({

          severity: 'info',

          life: environment.modalTime,

          summary: 'Chat creado con éxito',

          detail: '' + x,

        });

        this.router.navigate(['/chat/home']);

      });

    } else {

     this.messageService.add({

        severity: 'error',

       life: environment.modalTime,

      summary: 'Formulario incorrecto',

      detail:

         'Asegúrese de rellenar todos los campos respetando el formato.',

      });

    }

  }}
```

**crearchat.component.spec.ts**

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

 

import { CrearChatComponent } from './crearchat.component';

 

describe('CrearChatComponent', () => {

  let component: CrearChatComponent;

  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CrearChatComponent>;

 

  beforeEach(async () => {

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({

      declarations: [ CrearChatComponent ]

    })

    .compileComponents();

  });

 

  beforeEach(() => {

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CrearChatComponent);

    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    fixture.detectChanges();

  });

 

  it('should create', () => {

    expect(component).toBeTruthy();

  });

});
```

**crearchat.module.ts**

```
import { CrearChatComponent } from './crearchat.component';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { CrearChatRoutingModule } from './crearchat-routing.module';

 

@NgModule({

  declarations: [CrearChatComponent],

  imports: [CommonModule, CrearChatRoutingModule,ReactiveFormsModule],

})

export class CrearChatModule {}
```

Gracias de antemano por las respuestas

Comment: solo pones el código y medio explicas como si supieras lo que quieres hacer y el error que tienes mmmmm

Comment: Hola, primero que nada no entiendo por que agregaste varios saltos de línea en tu código, es realmente molesto de leer, y te recomendaría que no lo hagas. Segundo, no queda claro cuál es tu problema en específico. Podrías agregar el error que obtienes o que esperas obtener vs lo que estas obteniendo?